# How to unset the comment form in drupal 7?

Tags: forms, comments, drupal-7

In drupal 7 the comment form appears on every node. I want to unset the comment form and display a link of "Add new comment" which will display the comment form on click.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

On the edit page for the content type, under "*Comment settings*" there is an option labelled "*Show reply form on the same page as comments*". When that option is **unchecked** then the comment form will appear on it's own page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to

Structure >> Content types >> Then edit the content type e.g Pages >> then on the tab there a tab called "Comment fields"

You can add and remove comment fields there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Probably you could not understand my question. I want an 'add new comment' link on every node instead of displaying the comment form on every node. As in drupal 7 the comment form displays on every node instead of the link.

Comment: why not use jQuery to hide the #comment-wrapper then add a field on your content and then use that as the trigger id or class. It's just an idea, i know it sounds dirty but i would do it that way.  [link]http://api.jquery.com/hide/ [/link]

Comment: Any Idea about the code? What could should I write? And where I should write the code?